# MailKit STARTTLS Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send emails to users using "smtp.office365.com" as a server. I am using my personal outlook id for authentication purposes and as a sender email.

I am using MailKit to send mail.

I'm getting this `The SMTP server does not support the STARTTLS extension.` exception at client.Connect() method.
Here's the code

```cs
public bool SendCode(SMTPMessageModel messageModel)
{
    try
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name Surname", "abc@mail.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Admin", messageModel.Destination));
        message.Subject = messageModel.Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = messageModel.Body
        };
        using(var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            // client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, false);
            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            client.Authenticate("abc@mail.com", "123456789");
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when use
`client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, false);` which says not to use SSL, it connects(client.Connect() works) but the Send method gives me this exception :
`5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]`

Really have no clue what's going on.

One thing to note is when I am using my company's email server(encryption method TLS) and company email id for testing purpose, it's working fine
but when I am using client's email server(encryption method STARTTLS), with their email id, it's throwing exception even while testing.

Comment: Maybe try `StartTlsWhenAvailable` or `SslOnConnect`

Comment: You are using port 587 which uses TLS and are missing the line use ssl.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: @Charlieface, tried both, same exceptions

Comment: @jdweng, I am using `MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()`, and not `System.Net.Mail`

Comment: What about `Auto`? Also what about port 465?

Comment: @Charlieface, It throws exception saying to use port 587 or STARTTLS setting

Comment: Are you on the latest version of MailKit? Which exact version/build number of .NET and Windows?

Comment: @Charlieface, MailKit 3.3.0, .NET Framework 4.6.2, Windows 10

Comment: The setting that you need to use is what your email server requires.  It not smtp.office365 but your email account abc@mail.com.   smtp.office has different setting depending on domain.  See answer here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cf2f11d-857a-42fd-9f43-7cb70bfe2a7a/573-starttls-is-required-to-send-mail?forum=Exch2016GD&force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng, I don't think this is going to work as server is different from username. Also in the link, the problem didn't get resolved.

Comment: SMTP requires the credentials and the FROM address to be the same same account.  It is not the library, but the mail server that requires both to be the same.  office365 is just an application with different settings and the domain (like gmail) can have different settings like use SSL (or not) and Port number may be different.  You cannot use your personal ID on a corporate network.  It will fail.  You personal ID is a different domain and in the corporate world there is a firewall and the connection will go to a proxy server that will not had your personal credentials.

Comment: @jdweng, I am using the same id for the things that you mentioned, but no luck. My company's server's encryption is TLS. When I am using my company server and email for testing purpose, it's working as expected but when I am using my client's server, whose encryption method is STARTTLS with there email id, it's giving me this exception.

Comment: Inside a company network all SMTP port numbers are forwarded to the company email proxy server where credentials are checked.  Your client account is not using your company email server so the credentials will fail.  The code will work on your home PC.  If you can connect to a WIFI at a business near your company that will also work.  But inside your company firewall you will not be able to connect to an outside email server.